# Installing pip on Bluehost

Tags: python, installation, pip

I have successfully installed python 2.7.11 on a shared Bluehost server.

In the home directory I installed get-pip.py When I run that now,

```
# python get-pip.py
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in ./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

But when I try to run pip I get,

```
usernmame@example.com [~]# pip
-bash: pip: command not found
```

Why is pip not running? How can I check what python packages are installed?

My ~/.bashrc looks like this,

```
# .bashrc
export PATH=$HOME/python/Python-2.7.11/:$PATH
# User specific aliases and functions
alias mv='mv -i'
alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

Additionally,

```
# echo $PATH
/usr/local/jdk/bin:/home2/username/python/Python-2.7.11/:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/home2/username/perl5/bin:/ramdisk/php/54/bin:/usr/php/54/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/home2/username/bin
```

**EDIT:**

My attempt to add the path to $PATH in ~/.bashrc

```
export PATH=$HOME/python/Python-2.7.11/:$HOME/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/:$PATH
```

But it doesn't work, same error.

Thanks

Comment: Probably because `./python/lib/python2.7/site-packages` is not on your `$PATH`.

Comment: I added the contents of ~/.bashrc to the question. Thanks

Comment: Added the output from # echo $PATH

Comment: Actually, in your case, you can just use `python -m pip`. For example, if you want to install a package called "package-of-interest", you could do `python -m pip install package-of-interest`.

Comment: Brilliant that works, and allows me install any Python package. Thanks for your help

Comment: Awesome, I will write an answer so that others who have a similar problem have something to work with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run `pip` by invoking the `-m` option when you use `python` to run `pip`. Suppose you want to use `pip` to install a Python package called "package-of-interest" from PyPI. Then, you can install it by running:

```
python -m pip install package-of-interest
```

Comment: This is kind of a work around, it should be possible to set the PATH variable in ~/.bashrc

Comment: The best way in my opinion is to install `pip` using your package manager because most likely `pip` installed in this manner will end up on your `$PATH`.

Comment: I am doing this on a hosting companies server.  don't what Linux distro they use or the package manager. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, the fact that `$HOME/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` exists (or at least I assume it does because you tried to add it to `$PATH`) means your home directory is set up in a uncommon way.

Comment: Why is that path unusual? What would you expect it to be? I really need to get this to work without the -m option.